# Increase performances of TableLayoutPanel - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have made a `TableLayoutPanel` (Size: 30 rows and 30 columns) with each cell containing a `button`. However it takes multiples seconds for the `TableLayoutPanel` to generate itself. Is there ways to reduce this time? I already saw the `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` functions but they don't seem to improve the generating time at all.

Any others tips for improving performances of a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Here is the code for generating the TableLayoutPanel

```
    //LifeField is a derived class of TableLayoutPanel that I created
    public LifeField(int x, int y)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        RowCount = ROW_COUNT;
        ColumnCount = COLUMN_COUNT;
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        Dock = DockStyle.None;
        AutoSize = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            this.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            this.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent));
        }

        //Fill the TableLayoutPanel with Cell which is a derived class of Button
        SuspendLayout();
        Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
            {

                Cell cell = new Cell();


                Controls.Add(cell, j, i);
            }
        }
        Visible = true;
        ResumeLayout();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that generates this layout? Is *Size 30x30* a measure in Pixels or the cells count (implying 900 buttons)?

Comment: 30x30 indicates indeed the number of cells in the TableLayoutPanel